# Creating Intent results in "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()'"

Tags: kotlin, android-notifications, wear-os

I am trying to follow the code on Google for [creating a notification on Wear OS devices](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating).

```
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.WearableExtender

class MainActivity : WearableActivity() {


    val notificationId = 1
    // The channel ID of the notification.
    val id = "my_channel_01"
    // Build intent for notification content
    val viewPendingIntent = Intent(this, com.alborz.innout.MainActivity::class.java).let { viewIntent ->
        viewIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_EVENT_ID, notificationId)
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, viewIntent, 0)
    }
    // Notification channel ID is ignored for Android 7.1.1
    // (API level 25) and lower.
    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id)
        .setLocalOnly(true)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
        .setContentTitle("TITLE")
        .setContentText("TEXT")
        .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent)
```

Later I try to activate the notification, like this:

```
    button_in.setOnClickListener {
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).apply {
            notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build())
        }
    }
```

But I am getting an error which I do not understand. (I am super new to Kotlin so might have missed something obvious)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.alb.innout/com.alb.innout.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2844)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:142)
        at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:130)
        at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:6082)
        at com.alb.innout.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.kt:46)
```

Line 46 is `val viewPendingIntent = Intent ...`

Comment: Yo could use 

val integrator = IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(this)        integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE)
 integrator.initiateScan()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put this Intent and notification setup inside a function and call the function when it’s time to send the notification. The way you have it now, the Intent is created at the time the Activity is instantiated, which is before `onCreate()` and too early for it to be passed around as the `this` argument of functions and constructors that want to use its Context.

Comment: thank you, i put all the code in one function, now i get no errors but nothing happens instead. I will create a new question